# Cant figure out the null pointer exception

Tags: java, pointers, nullpointerexception, null

Please help me figure out the null pointer exception. I am not able to understand which variable or object is null.and hoe do i fix it ?

```
package coll.org;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SnakeAndladder1 {
ArrayList<String> name1=new ArrayList<String>(); //an array to store players names

public int throwdice() //to calculate the dice value
{
    return (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
}

public int ladder(int curscore)
{
    Hashtable ld = new Hashtable();
    ld.put(15,30);
    ld.put(45,71);
    ld.put(25,62);
    ld.put(81,91);
    ld.put(9,39);
    Object v=ld.get(curscore);
    return (int)v;
}
public int snake(int curscore)
{
    Hashtable ld = new Hashtable();
    ld.put(29,11);
    ld.put(81,48);
    ld.put(30,6);
    ld.put(92,71);
    ld.put(58,19);
    Object v=ld.get(curscore);
    return (int)v;
}


public boolean Game (String name1){
    int score=0;
    String name;
    int v=0;
    name=name1.toString();
        System.out.println("Click y to roll dice");
        Scanner in2=new Scanner(System.in);
        String yes=in2.nextLine();
        if(yes.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            v=throwdice();
            System.out.println("dice value:"+v);
        }
        score=score+v;
        if(score==100)
        {
            System.out.println("User:"+name+"got"+v+".Winner!!!");
            return false;
        }
        if (score>100)
        {
            score=score-v;
            System.out.println("Current score of"+name+"is"+score);
            return true;
        }

        int s1=ladder(score);
        if(s1==score)
        {
            score=snake(score);
            System.out.println("Current score of"+name+"is"+score);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            score=s1;
            System.out.println("Current score of"+name+"is"+score);
            return true;
        }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int l=0;
boolean flag=true;
System.out.println("Enter the number of players:");
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Players names in order:");
ArrayList<String> name1=new ArrayList<String>(); //an array to store players names
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    Scanner in1=new Scanner(System.in);
    String name2=in1.nextLine();
    name1.add(name2);
}

SnakeAndladder1 players[];
players = new SnakeAndladder1[n];
while(flag)
  {
    while(l<n)
    {
        flag = players[l].Game(name1.get(l)); //----Error occuring here.Its a null pointer 
    }                                                exception
  }
 }
}
```

the stack trace is :

```
Enter the number of players:
3
Enter Players names in order:
raghav
kishan
sr
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at coll.org.SnakeAndladder1.main(SnakeAndladder1.java:107)
```

Comment: How did you debug your code? Did you use break points and step through line by line?

Comment: you can't typecast `Object` to `int`

Answer (score 3):

The following initializes the array with `n` nulls:

```
players = new SnakeAndladder1[n];
```

To avoid the NPE, you need to create the objects before calling `Game()` on them.

Answer (score 1):

```
SnakeAndladder1 players[];
players = new SnakeAndladder1[n];
```

Add this after above:

```
for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
{
    players[i] = new SnakeAndladder1();
}
```

This will initialize an object at each element of the array.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do .size() to an array it has to be .length

Comment: you should avoid this if it is in the loop think something.

Comment: I don't understand what you just said it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Using length is good practice because it is the actual size of the array.  You should not use another variable to store the size of the array when you can call a method that already has a variable that stores the size of the array.  This can help you avoid indexoutofbounds exception also it is more efficient.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your answer. instead of calling `players.length` in  `for ` loop it is better to call outside of loop and use it. so you can reduce no of calls. any way here you are creating `n` objects so you know `n`.

Comment: That's fine but you should do n = players.length right before the loop.  Although you won't see much if any performance difference when you do this.

Comment: @Rustam's comments here seem like a case of premature optimization.  Yes, the call to dereference an int in another object will be marginally slower than the call to read an int off of the stack in the current method, but unless `n` is enormous (in a game of Snakes and Ladders!), it won't matter in practice and the better code readability trumps the trivial performance improvement.

Comment: No problem glad I could help...do you mind marking this as correct if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

The `n` in your case is a null, since you're getting the value from the user. So it won't create the array as a finite array. They're all nulls.

Try to initialize the number first from the user and then initialize the array.